# My Python while loop is not terminating and I don't know why

Tags: python, while-loop, collatz

It seems like the while loop should terminate once the start int == 1, but it keeps going. It also seems it's not actually printing the values....just 0

> Given a positive integer n, the following rules will always create a
> sequence that ends with 1, called the hailstone sequence:

- If n is even, divide it by 2
- If n is odd, multiply it by 3 and add 1(i.e. 3n +1)
- Continue until n is 1

> Write a program that reads an
> integer as input and prints the hailstone sequence starting with the
> integer entered. Format the output so that ten integers, each
> separated by a tab character (\t), are printed per line.
>
> The output format can be achieved as follows: print(n, end='\t')

Ex: If the input is:

```
25
```

the output is:

```
25   76   38   19   58   29   88   44   22   11 
34   17   52   26   13   40   20   10   5    16 
8    4    2    1
```

My code:

```
''' Type your code here. '''
start = int()

while True:
    print(start, end='\t')
    if start % 2 == 0:
        start = start/2
        print(start, end='\t')
    elif start % 2 == 1:
        start = (start *3)+1
        print(start, end='\t')
    if start == 1:
        print(start, end='\t')
        break

print(start, end='\t')
```

Program errors displayed here

```
Program generated too much output.
Output restricted to 50000 characters.

Check program for any unterminated loops generating output.
```

Program output displayed here

```
0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.
```

Comment: Use integer division (`//` instead of `/`)

Comment: Also, did you mean: `start = int(input())`?

Comment: @ssp That's not necessary. `1.0 == 1` is true.

Comment: The program never terminates, because you checked for odd first and changed `1` to `4`.

Comment: @quamrana thanks, I did forget to complete the start = int(input()) statement. Now that I've corrected that, the loop is terminating and I'm getting some numbers to output. I just need to try to figure out why its printing each number twice now. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Well, you *do* have lots of print statements. I recommend keeping only the one after `while True:`

Answer (score 0):

Your loop isn't terminating because you used 0 as an input and as `0 % 2 == 0` is true and `0/2=0` you become stuck in an infinite loop. you could fix this by raising an exception if start is `<=0` like this:

```
start = int(input())
if start <=0:
    raise Exception('Start must be strictly positive')
while True:
    print(start, end='\t')
    if not start % 2:
        start //= 2
    elif start % 2:
        start = 3*start+1
    if start == 1:
        break
```

Comment: I think you can hoist the `0` check above the `while True:` since any non conforming numbers can only come from the user input.

Comment: yep fair point, done